# Code First submission null reference for model list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I'm submitting to the db using CF EF, I'm getting a null reference exception on the model list within the page's model, here: `db.colleges.SaveChanges(college);` . The model on the page is `college` and each `college` has a list of `student`. When I add a break point on the ActionResult and hover over the parsed in college value, it shows null on the students property, when I would expect a count of 1 (or however many I add to it).

What have I missed?

**Code**

Offending action method within controller

```
private CollegeContext db = new CollegeContext();
public ActionResult StudentManager()
        {
            return PartialView("StudentView", new Student());
        }
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "collegeId,name")] College college)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.colleges.Add(college);

                foreach(var s in college.students)
                {
                    var stu = new Student()
                    {
                       firstName = s.firstName,
                       lastName = s.lastName
                    };
                    db.students.Add(stu);
                }

                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(college);
        }
```

Create page

```
@model Register.Models.College

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>College</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="editorRowsStudents">
            @foreach (var item in Model.students)
            {
                @Html.Partial("StudentView", item)
            }
        </div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Add", "StudentManager", null, new { id = "addItemStudents", @class="btn btn-default" })

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#addItemStudents').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("StudentManager")',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) { $("#editorRowsStudents").append(html); }
                });
                return false;
            });
            $('#editorRowsStudents').on('click', '.deleteRow', function () {
                $(this).closest('.editorRow').remove();
            });
        });
</script>
}
```

Student partial

```
@model Register.Models.Student

<div class="editorRow">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("students"))
    {
        <div class="ui-grid-c ui-responsive">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.firstName)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.lastName)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c">
                <span>
                    <span class="dltBtn">
                        <a href="#" class="deleteRow">X</a>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Models

```
[Table("College")]
    public class College
    {
        [Key]
        public int collegeId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        // navigation property to keep track of the student(s) that belong to the college
        public virtual IList<Student> students { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Student")]
    public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int studentId { get; set; }
        public int collegeId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("collegeId")]
        // navigation property to keep track of which college the student belongs
        public College college { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public string lastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like a variable or property is null. Set breakpoints and step through the code to find the null variable/property. You could additionally post the entire exception message, which might tell you which property is null, but that doesn't change the fact you'll need to debug your code.

Comment: The students property list of student is returning null, but they're created in the partial through BeginCollectionItem using the StudentManager within the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `[Bind(include = "...")]` attribute excludes property `students` from binding. Remove it (and if you ever find yourself using it, don't, use a view model instead)